# Determining cascaded shadow map split ranges

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow

I'm doing cascaded shadow maps, and I believe I have a problem concerning the way I do the split comparison to select the proper shadow map. As it stands, the shadow mapping works overall but in a few cases at certain angles it does not work.

Currently the lighting shader stage looks like this:

```
"#version 420                                                                                                                   

const float DEPTH_BIAS = 0.00005;                                                                                               

layout(std140) uniform UnifDirLight                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                               
    mat4 mVPMatrix[4];                                                                                                          
    mat4 mCamViewMatrix;    
    vec4 mSplitDistance;                                                                                                    
    vec4 mLightColor;                                                                                                           
    vec4 mLightDir;                                                                                                             
    vec4 mGamma;                                                                                                                
    vec2 mScreenSize;                                                                                                           
} UnifDirLightPass;                                                                                                             

layout (binding = 2) uniform sampler2D unifPositionTexture;                                                                     
layout (binding = 3) uniform sampler2D unifNormalTexture;                                                                       
layout (binding = 4) uniform sampler2D unifDiffuseTexture;                                                                      
layout (binding = 6) uniform sampler2DArrayShadow unifShadowTexture;                                                            

out vec4 fragColor;                                                                                                             

void main()                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                               
    vec2 texcoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / UnifDirLightPass.mScreenSize;                                                             

    vec3 worldPos = texture(unifPositionTexture, texcoord).xyz;                                                                 
    vec3 normal   = normalize(texture(unifNormalTexture, texcoord).xyz);                                                        
    vec3 diffuse  = texture(unifDiffuseTexture, texcoord).xyz;                                                                  

    vec4 camPos = UnifDirLightPass.mCamViewMatrix * vec4(worldPos, 1.0);     // legit way of determining the split?                                            

    int index = 3;                                                                        
    if (camPos .z > UnifDirLightPass.mSplitDistance.x)                                                                           
       index = 0;                                                                                                              
    else if (camPos .z > UnifDirLightPass.mSplitDistance.y)                                                                      
       index = 1;                                                                                                            
    else if (camPos .z > UnifDirLightPass.mSplitDistance.z)                                                                      
       index = 2;                                                                                                              

    vec4 projCoords = UnifDirLightPass.mVPMatrix[index] * vec4(worldPos, 1.0);                                                  
    projCoords.w    = projCoords.z - DEPTH_BIAS;                                                                                
    projCoords.z    = float(index);                                                                                             
    float visibilty = texture(unifShadowTexture, projCoords);                                                                   

    float angleNormal = clamp(dot(normal, UnifDirLightPass.mLightDir.xyz), 0, 1);                                               

    fragColor = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * visibilty * angleNormal * UnifDirLightPass.mLightColor;                                    
}
```

And the "mSplitDistance", each component is the center fardistance of the frustrum for that split, multiplied by the main cameras view matrix

```
Vec4 camFarDistCenter;
CameraFrustrum cameraFrustrum = CalculateCameraFrustrum(nearDistArr[cascadeIndex], farDistArr[cascadeIndex], lighting.mCameraPosition, lighting.mCameraDirection, camFarDistCenter);

.....

camFarDistCenter = lighting.mCameraViewMatrix * camFarDistCenter;
splitDistances[cascadeIndex] = camFarDistCenter.z;
```

Here's how I create the camera frustrum for each split, if its of interest, I believe this is a pretty common alghorithm:

```
CameraFrustrum CalculateCameraFrustrum(const float minDist, const float maxDist, const Vec3& cameraPosition, const Vec3& cameraDirection, Vec4& camFarZ)
{
    CameraFrustrum ret = { Vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
                           Vec4(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f) };

    const Vec3 forwardVec = glm::normalize(cameraDirection);
    const Vec3 rightVec   = glm::normalize(glm::cross(forwardVec, Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
    const Vec3 upVec      = glm::normalize(glm::cross(rightVec, forwardVec));

    const Vec3 nearCenter = cameraPosition + forwardVec * minDist;
    const Vec3 farCenter  = cameraPosition + forwardVec * maxDist;

    camFarZ = Vec4(farCenter, 1.0);

    const float nearHeight = tan(glm::radians(70.0f) / 2.0f) * minDist;
    const float nearWidth = nearHeight * 1920.0f / 1080.0f;
    const float farHeight  = tan(glm::radians(70.0f) / 2.0f) * maxDist;
    const float farWidth = farHeight * 1920.0f / 1080.0f;

    ret[0] = Vec4(nearCenter - (upVec * nearHeight) - (rightVec * nearWidth), 1.0);
    ret[1] = Vec4(nearCenter + (upVec * nearHeight) - (rightVec * nearWidth), 1.0);
    ret[2] = Vec4(nearCenter + (upVec * nearHeight) + (rightVec * nearWidth), 1.0);
    ret[3] = Vec4(nearCenter - (upVec * nearHeight) + (rightVec * nearWidth), 1.0);

    ret[4] = Vec4(farCenter - upVec * farHeight - rightVec * farWidth, 1.0);
    ret[5] = Vec4(farCenter + upVec * farHeight - rightVec * farWidth, 1.0);
    ret[6] = Vec4(farCenter + upVec * farHeight + rightVec * farWidth, 1.0);
    ret[7] = Vec4(farCenter - upVec * farHeight + rightVec * farWidth, 1.0);

    return ret;
}
```

Is it sound to do the split comparison in camera space like I do? Is that a potential problem?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Any missing information?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void CalculateCameraFrustrum(glm::mat4& projectionMatrix, 
                             glm::mat4  viewMatrix,       // viewMatrix = light POV
                             glm::vec3  camera            // camera = eye position + eye direction
                             float      zNear, 
                             float      zFar, 
                             glm::vec4  point[4])         // point[4] = shadow map boundaries
    glm::mat4 shadMvp =  projectionMatrix * (viewMatrix * glm::translate(camera));
    glm::vec3 transf;
    float     maxX = zNear, minX = zFar, 
              maxY = zNear, minY = zFar;

    int i = -1;
    while (++i < 4)
    {
        transf = shadMvp * point[i];

        transf.x /= transf.w;
        transf.y /= transf.w;

        if(transf.x > maxX) 
            maxX = transf.x;
        if(transf.x < minX) 
            minX = transf.x;
        if(transf.y > maxY) 
            maxY = transf.y;
        if(transf.y < minY) 
            minY = transf.y;
    }

    float scaleX  =  2.0f / (maxX - minX),
          scaleY  =  2.0f / (maxY - minY),
          offsetX = -0.5f * (maxX + minX) * scaleX,
          offsetY = -0.5f * (maxY + minY) * scaleY;

    shadMvp = glm::mat4(1); // Identity matrix

    shadMvp[0][0] = scaleX;
    shadMvp[1][1] = scaleY;
    shadMvp[0][3] = offsetX;
    shadMvp[1][3] = offsetY;

    projectionMatrix *= shadMvp;
} // No need to calculate view frustum splitting, 
  // only the boundaries of the shadow maps levels are needed (glm::ortho(...)).
  // :)
```